# .NET The input stream is not a valid binary format tcp

Tags: .net, serialization, bytestream

Please tell where i can have problem in my code?

I serialize the data into a list of objects, then send it to the tcp server for further manipulations
This is how serialization works:

```
var objList = new List<object>
{
  path,
  attachmentContext.LogItemInfo.Attachment
};

byte[] toServer;
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
      bf.Serialize(ms, objList);
      toServer = ms.ToArray();
}

_client.SendAsync(toServer);
```

So some transmissions are serialized successfully, then somewhere on the random it fails
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect that the problem here is "framing", meaning: the `buffer` that you're processing does not contain exactly one message. It could contain the start of a message, or an entire message and part of the next, either of which can cause problems. TCP is a stream, not a series of messages. The good news is that `BinaryFormatter` *has framing built in anyway*, so honestly: you could just use the `NetworkStream` directly and it should *just work*. Otherwise, you're going to need to implement your own framing layout, and make sure that the receiving code reads an entire frame before processing data *and* deals correctly with any over-read, i.e. it should retain any bytes that belong to the *next* frame.

The bad news is that you *should not ever use `BinaryFormatter`*, and **in particular** you shouldn't use it in a socket server (where the client should always be considered hostile). [Further reading](https://blog.marcgravell.com/2020/03/why-do-i-rag-on-binaryformatter.html).

To investigate whether framing is the problem:

- at the client, log the hex of each message that you're sending
- at the client, log the hex of each message that you're trying to process
- now compare them; they should match message-to-message ("starting the same" isn't enough; they need to be the same length, and identical throughout)